# Matlab - create new matrix from combining two other

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have
two matrices:

```
A = [1 2; 3 4; 2 6; 4 7];
B = [2 4; 4 4; 4 3; 5 8];
```

How can I create new matrix, that it would have order like, first A row, then first B row, then second A row, then second B row etc.

Like this:

```
C = [1 2; 2 4; 3 4; 4 4; 2 6; 4 3; 4 7; 5 8];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I n your specific example, you can write:

```
C(1:2:7,:) = A ; C(2:2:8,:) = B
```

See:

```
octave:1> A = [1 2; 3 4; 2 6; 4 7];
octave:2> B = [2 4; 4 4; 4 3; 5 8];
octave:3> C(1:2:7,:) = A ; C(2:2:8,:) = B
C =

   1   2
   2   4
   3   4
   4   4
   2   6
   4   3
   4   7
   5   8

octave:4>
```

Now assuming `A` and `B` have the same size, you can write

```
C(1:2:2*size(A,1)-1,:) = A ; C(2:2:2*size(A,1),:) = B
```

to be more general.

Comment: How could I write this with `for` loop as if I had long matrices? I would have to manually write like this for many rows.

Comment: Not sure I understand. You mean that you have more matrices than `A` and `B` or that `A` and `B` have many rows?

Comment: Both matrices A and B are same length, but they have more rows than I give in an example. So I asked if there was some more general way to do this

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to get your hands dirty with `reshape`-ing:

```
C = reshape( [A.';B.'], 2, [] ).';
```

Why this works?
Matlab stores its matrices in memory as a column stack. Transposing `A` and `B` and stacking their rows (now columns) one after the other in memory creates a 4-by-`n` matrix with the proper order of elements. Now we `reshape` this matrix to have 2 rows only and transpose it back to get the desired result. Ta-da!

Comment: Why the `.'` rather than simply `'` ?

Comment: @damienfrancois nice question: if you are working with real-valued numbers, then there's no difference. However, for complex numbers `'` gives the hermitian transpose (transpose+complex conjugate) while `.'` only transposes the matrices. Since most people do not work daily with complex numbers it is more common to use `'` for transpose, but if you want to be more strict `.'` is in place. I once happened to write a small script that involved complex numbers and it took me ages to debug until I realize I used `'` where I should have used `.'`. So, it's up to you.